# Python 3.6 Env: ImportError: No module named http.client

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

I'm trying to use the Python YouTube Data API Python script that allows to upload a video: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/uploading_a_video#Sample_Code. Note that it's compatible Python 2.x, not 3.X. So I've updated its code by replacing the first import ( `import httplib` ) by this import: `import http.client` .

When I run this script, the following error is shown:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/home/xzerzxez/pycharm_projects/zerde/upload_video.py", line 3, in 
>       import http.client
>   ImportError: No module named http.client
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

- PyCharm's used environment: my Ubuntu's one
- Python version: /usr/bin/python3.6
- Pertinent packages installed: httplib2, request, requests
- Available packages to install: micropython-http.client, pycopy-http.client, yieldfrom.http.client

How to solve this problem?

Edit: of course I also made other littles changes to the code to make it compatible Python 3.X, but it's off-topic :-) .

Comment: what stops you from using python2 your script is written for?

Comment: Because I use this script from anothrr, python 3.6, script

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the shebang to `#!/usr/bin/python3`